# Sorting list in C#

Tags: c#, list, c#-4.0, collections, arraylist

I have a list of custom type.  And the custom type is

```
public class PossibleMatch
    {
        public PossibleMatch()
        {
            StoreIds = new List<long>();
            OrderLineIds = new List<long>();
        }
        public IList<long> StoreIds { get; set; }
        public IList<long> OrderLineIds { get; set; }
    }
```

I have to sort the list in such a way item with less number of stores and more number of order lines should be at top.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

LINQ has just the methods for this.

Try the following to order by matches with the fewest StoreIds first and then to sub order by matches with the most OrderLineIds:

```
 var possibleMatches = new List<PossibleMatch>();
 var ordered = possibleMatches.OrderBy(pm => pm.StoreIds.Count).ThenByDesc(pm => pm.OrderLineIds.Count);
```

Or to order by matches with the most OrderLineIds first and then to sub order by matches with the fewest StoreIds:

```
var ordered = possibleMatches.OrderByDesc(pm => pm.OrderLineIds.Count).ThenBy(pm => pm.StoreIds.Count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Build Custom Comparer:

```
public class PossibleMatchComparer: IComparer<PossibleMatch>
{
    public int Compare(PossibleMatch x, PossibleMatch y)
    {
        if (x.StoreIds.Count < y.StoreIds.Count) return -1;
        if (x.StoreIds.Count > y.StoreIds.Count) return 1;

        return y.OrderLineIds.Count - x.OrderLineIds.Count;
    }
}
```

So you can use:

```
list.Sort(new PossibleMatchComparer());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @Cuong. How the custom comparer differs from LINQ's OrderBy

Comment: @Naresh it sorts the list in-place instead of returning an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Thanks Cuong, I have not yet tried it. Will try it and update.